# Binding a BitmapImage obtained from a ByteStream to an ImageBrush on UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I am developing for the Universal Windows Platform. I am pulling in an image from a website as a base64 string and converting it to a byte array using `byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(srcString);` the converting that  to a BitmapImage with the following code:

```
public async static Task<BitmapImage> ImageFromBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
    return image;        
}
```

It appears like this pulls in my image correctly as dimension properties of the image in the BitmapImage object are populated correctly. The problem is that I need to use this image object as the background of a GridView Item template using an image brush with the following XAML code:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:data" >
                <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="190"
                Height="270"
                BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkBlue"
                >

                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{x:Bind Image}"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Title:" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Name="Block" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{x:Bind Title}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have the back code set up correctly because if I feed a local URI in to the Image bound variable then everything works flawlessly. But, since the URI property in the BitmapImage I made is null, I am unable to just get the URI for it and use that for the binding. Getting the image as a byte array is the only way I am able to do it. Is there a way to use this image I pulled in with a byte stream and bind it to my XAML code?

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: Does it work with `ImageSource="{Binding Image}"`? You should also show us the declaration of your Image property.

Comment: Thanks Clemens! That actually worked!! Does Binding have more compatibility than x:Bind then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
```

instead of

```
ImageSource="{x:Bind Image}"
```

While `x:Bind` requires an exact type match,  `Binding` takes advantage of built-in conversion from several source types (e.g. `string`, `Uri`, `byte[]`) to `ImageSource`.

Comment: Is there something different I would need to do if I wanted to access this image outside of the Item Template? Say just an image object under the main outside grid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you have an Image property in your view model, binding to it should always look like shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the ImageSource

```
ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
```

Much thanks to Clemens!